# Install jekyll blog on VPS

Tags: jekyll, vps

I'm trying very hard to install [Jekyll blog](https://jekyllrb.com)
on my VPS because i want to host my website on my VPS not on github pages also I have followed the steps here
`https://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/`

but i didnt succeed is there any one can help me to step by step install jekyll blog on my hosting

Comment: @Martin i installed ruby and jekyll on my server but when i go to the blog link it's like something wrong see this pic [link](http://i.imgur.com/FgdHeHZ.png)

Comment: @AmeerAssadi Exactly, what the error you got that resulted in what you linked?

Comment: @AliAlmoullim http://i.imgur.com/FgdHeHZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hwsA.png) you attached in your comment, you probably uploaded jekyll files and not the static files which exists in the folder `_site`.

So what you have to do is, install jekyll using npm or RubyGems in your own machine, setup everything in your jekyll files, then use the command `jekyll serve` to build and check if everything is generated successfully by going to `localhost:4000`, if everything went well, then go to your jekyll directory and take the files inside `_site` and upload them to your webhost using FTP

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider to NOT install Jekyll on your VPS.

You can install it on your local machine. Jekyll is a static site generator and generates flat HTML files in the '_site' folder. This folder can be easily transmitted through FTP to your VPS after an update.

Another way to let your VPS host your Jekyll site and NOT install Jekyll, is to let the guys from CloudCannon do the Jekyll part and let them connect to your VPS through FTP. CloudCannon will automatically push the static site to your VPS on update. You will get their CMS for free as a bonus.